# two multiple file uploader in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I have been trying to upload multiple photos twice in a single form in codeigniter project,though the photos are uploading correctly but the name of photos are not been returned as per desired. for example if am uploading a photo named 'a.jpg' in first uploader and 'b.jpg' in second uploader,the names i am getting are "a.jpg,b.jpg" for first and "b.jpg,b(1).jpg" for second case. below is the code attached.

controller:-

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Imageupload extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('imageupload_view', array('error' => ' ' ));
    }

    function doupload()
    {
        $name_array = array();
        $count = count($_FILES['userfile']['size']);
    //  echo $count;
        foreach($_FILES as $key=>$value)
        for($s=0; $s<=$count-1; $s++)
        {
            $_FILES['userfile']['name']=$value['name'][$s];
            $_FILES['userfile']['type']    = $value['type'][$s];
            $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $value['tmp_name'][$s];
            $_FILES['userfile']['error']       = $value['error'][$s];
            $_FILES['userfile']['size']    = $value['size'][$s];
            $config['upload_path'] = 'application/views/uploads';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '1000000';
            //$config['max_width']  = '1024';
            //$config['max_height']  = '768';
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->do_upload();
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            $name_array[] = $data['file_name'];
        }

        $names= implode(',', $name_array);
        return $names;
    }

    function doupload_1()
    {
        $name_array = array();
        $count = count($_FILES['file_1']['size']);
        echo $count;
        foreach($_FILES as $key=>$value)
        for($s=0; $s<=$count-1; $s++)
        {
            $_FILES['file_1']['name']=$value['name'][$s];
            $_FILES['file_1']['type']    = $value['type'][$s];
            $_FILES['file_1']['error']       = $value['error'][$s];
            $_FILES['file_1']['tmp_name'] = $value['tmp_name'][$s];
            $_FILES['file_1']['size']    = $value['size'][$s];
            $config['upload_path'] = 'application/views/uploads';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '1000000';
            //$config['max_width']  = '1024';
            //$config['max_height']  = '768';
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->do_upload();
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            $name_array[] = $data['file_name'];
        }

        $names= implode(',', $name_array);
        return $names;
    }

    public function check()
    {
        $data = $this->doupload();
        $data_1 = $this->doupload_1();
        print_r($data);
        echo "<br>";
        print_r($data_1);
    }

}
?>
```

view:-

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo form_open_multipart('imageupload/check');?>
<input name="userfile[]" id="userfile" type="file" multiple="" />
<input name="file_1[]" id="file" type="file" multiple=""/>
<input type="submit" value="upload" />
<?php echo form_close() ?>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: i can't understand your question-plz calrify me?

Comment: do you want file name in encrypted form??

Comment: i want to store the file names in database,so the first field userfile should contain the name of files uploaded in doupload() function and file_1 should contain the name of files uploaded in doupload1() function

Comment: but why you are taking two uploader. Just take one uploader and by it you can upload multiple image like add button 'Add more image'.

Comment: tell me if this is your requirement . you have two file field in your html? and two function in code upload1 and upload ? you are uploading two two pic from both input field? but your both codeigniter code running four four time?

Comment: exactly,this is the problem @TariqHusain

Comment: i have seen your are echoing $count what does it return ?

Comment: check my old answer now i have got the problem @ Ajitej Kaushik

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got what the problem in your code. it is because your foreach on $_FILES not on $_FILES['userfile'] thats why $_FILES CONTAIN all the files not only userfile. and file_1

```
foreach($_FILES['userfile'] as $key=>$value)

foreach($_FILES['file_1'] as $key=>$value)
```

but still you have to change the below code according to foreach. 
if you find solution for your answer please givel like my answer and accept it .

Comment: its only returning the name of file uploaded with the first doupload() method.

Comment: you have uploaded the b.jpg with uplaoder one and again you are trying to upload it with uploader to thats why it returning you b(1.jpg)

Comment: i tried uploading photos with diff name,yet,its showing unwanted results.

Comment: its still not working,though i implemented as you mentioned!

Comment: its showing undefined index : name,and similar for type,temp_name,error,size.
i will be really greatful if u really help me with this. @Tariq Husain

Comment: okkay do one thing if the problem is still not solved zip the code and send me hussain.tariq642@gmail.com i will run it so i can fix the error .

Comment: and also i have told you  $_FILES['userfile']['name'] it work liek this now cz you have changed the foreach .. print_r inside the foreach and check how you getting the values.

Comment: Sir,i have mailed you,shared the folder on drive,kindly see. @Tariq Husain

Answer (score 0):

Please check below link to upload multi file in codeigniter

http://technet.massivetechnolab.co.in/multiple-image-uploading-using-codeigniter

Comment: actually i am aware of this technique but it only works if i have single field for multiple upload,but my case contains two fields for multiple uploads.

Answer (score 0):

Multi upload function

```
public function mupload ($field_name,$path = './botimage/') {

    $files = $_FILES;
    $cpt = count($_FILES[$field_name]['name']);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $cpt; $i++) {
        $config =  array(
            'upload_path'     => $path,
            'upload_url'      => upload_url('galeri/'),
            'allowed_types'   => "gif|jpg|png|jpeg",
            'overwrite'       => TRUE,
            'file_name'       => rand(0,999). time(),
            'max_size'        => "10000KB",
        );
        $data = array();
        // set the filter image types
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $_FILES['userfile']['name'] = $files[$field_name]['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['type'] = $files[$field_name]['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $files[$field_name]['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['error'] = $files[$field_name]['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile']['size'] = $files[$field_name]['size'][$i];

        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        if ($this->upload->do_upload()) {
            $tmp = $this->upload->data();
            $uploaded_file_data[$i] = $tmp["file_name"];
        } else {
            $errors[] = $this->upload->display_errors();
        }
    }

    $data["file_urls"] = implode(",",$uploaded_file_data);
    $data["errors"] = implode(" ",@$errors);

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: it is the same function as my method doupload()

Comment: the problem is i have two such function doupload() and doupload_1() as i have the requirement of uploading multiple photos twice,and its not working,but i use only doupload() and try to upload photos only once,its working fine!

Comment: the problem with my code is that even if i try to upload two files for first method and two files for second method,the loop is running 4 times in each method.